# How can you customize the response message of the post in django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to make a membership API using django rest frameworks.I made a code and checked that the function was working properly. In my current code, if the data of the email, password, and username are empty, the message is given as follows.

```
{
    "email": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "username": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
}
```

But after talking about this with my team's client developers, they said it was better to give a unified message as below.

```
{
    "message": "email field is required."
}
```

How can I customize the value like this? Here's my code.

```
class customSignUpView (GenericAPIView) :
    serializer_class = customRegisterSerializer

    def post (self, request) :
        user = request.data
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=user)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()

        user = User.objects.get(email=serializer.data['email'])

        token = RefreshToken.for_user(user).access_token

        current_site = get_current_site(request).domain
        relativeLink = reverse('emailVerify')
        
        absurls = F'http://{current_site}{relativeLink}?token={token}'
        email_body = F'Hi {user.username} Use link below to verify your email \n{absurls}'
        data = {'email_body': email_body, 'to_email': user.email, 'email_subject': 'Verify your email'}
        Util.send_email(data)
        
        return Response({'message': 'check your email.'}, status=201)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to customize `customRegisterSerializer` further by adding a custome `validate` method to it, just try to do something like this

```
class YourSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
     field1 = serializers.CharField(args)
     ...
     fieldn = serializers.CharField(args)

     def validate(self, data):
         error = {}
         if 'some_field' in data:
            test field is valid here
            if data['some_field'] is not valid:
                error['some_field'] = 'your message'
         .... ad nauseam
         if error:
             raise serializers.ValidationError(error)
         return data
```

pass the arguments as the `data` parameter, and you should be able to customize everything however you want

Comment: sorry but I can't understand your code because I use modelserializers ..

Comment: i see, maybe check out the django rest tutorial here, it doesn't include validate, but it should get you up to speed https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/

Answer (score 0):

First of all would like to say that the standard DRF approach to error messages is more universal, as it allows sending several messages for several fields in a unified way. I.e. that in the returned JSON `key` is the field name and `value` - the list of messages. Which also allows FE to display the messages next to the appropriate field.

Cause with the format you're trying to achieve comes the question of what kind of message to send if both `email` and `username` were not provided but are required (for e.g. should it be one message string or a list of `"{field_name} is required"` strings?).

But if you really need to achieve the approach you mentioned, let me elaborate on the answer by @vencaslac. So in your case the serializer should roughly look like:

```py
class CustomRegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     ...

     def validate(self, data):
         if not data.get("email"):
             raise serializers.ValidationError({"message": "email field is required."})
         return data
```

The `validate()` method is the same for both `Serializer` and `ModelSerializer`. You can find more info in the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#object-level-validation). But again, with this approach you need to figure out an answer to the question I mentioned above.

Comment: @leedjango can you please let me know whether this worked?